# Spring boot is not able to get configuration file from my file system

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to build a sample app on Spring boot and spring cloud.
I have written my database and hibernate configuration in **config.properties** property file which is located in my desktop and I want my spring boot to make use of this configuration.

My project have 3 modules

- API
- DataLayer
- ServiceLayer

This is the code that I have mentioned in the application.property file of API

**spring.profiles.active=native
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocation=C:/Users/DEV/Desktop/configuration/config.properties**

and the property file of DataLayer and ServiceLayer is empty

But when I run the API I am getting the following error

```html
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
 If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
 If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could any one help me with this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share spring.datasource.url part of the properties file (without any sensitive information, of course)? Seems to be missing. Also double check your Spring Data dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is can not be done from your API module. You added configuration server properties to your 'client' (from configuration point of view) application.

If you want to use [Spring Cloud Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/) to configure your project you should have separate application that will manage your configuration. Let's call it `config-server`. (You should properly configure maven or gradle dependencies, see documentation) To configure usage of `native` profile in the `config-server` in `application.properties` you have to add properties that you mentioned in the question (example for `native` profile).

```
spring.profiles.active=native
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocation=file:<path-to-the-directory-with-conf-files> or classpath:/<path-to-the-directory-with-conf-files>
```

Note: `config-server` can handle configuration for lot of services. 
More can be found in the documentation [Spring Cloud Config Server section](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.0.1.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_spring_cloud_config_server).

Then in your API (or any other module) which is a spring boot app you should add `spring-cloud-config-client` dependency and add `bootstrap.properties` (or .yml) configuration file. There your should add properties that will describe communication with `config-server`. By default `config-server` listens on port 8888.

```
spring.application.name=<your app name>    
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888 # this is also default value for this property
```

At start-up it will go by http to `config-server` and fetch your configuration properties based on service name (`spring.application.name`). 
More can be found in [Spring Cloud Config client section](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.0.1.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_spring_cloud_config_client)

Important: make sure your properly organize files in your configuration directory (which is used by `native` profile by `config-server`), find some samples. Property files naming are important. For start you can try to use `your-application-name.properties`

Comment: I tried what you said,Now i am getting this when i run API project.

Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
Located environment: name=Config-Server, profiles=[default], label=null, version=null, state=null
Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='configService', propertySources=[]}
No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default

and getting the same error as what i mentioned in my question, do I have to add dependency for JPA and MYSQL in config-server project?

Comment: You shouldn't add it to config-server because your are not using them. Same about other projects. Spring Boot has concept of autoconfiguration. If you have specific dependencies spring boot will try to initialize them and fail if you don't have configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have **file:** prefixed to the property file location.

Documentation from https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html

There is also a “native” profile in the Config Server that does not use Git but loads the config files from the local classpath or file system (any static URL you want to point to with spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations). To use the native profile, launch the Config Server with spring.profiles.active=native.

- [Note]
  *Remember to use the file: prefix for file resources (the default without a prefix is usually the classpath). As with any Spring Boot
  configuration, you can embed ${}-style environment placeholders, but
  remember that absolute paths in Windows require an extra / (for
  example, file:///${user.home}/config-repo).*
- [Warning]
  *The default value of the searchLocations is identical to a local Spring Boot application (that is, [classpath:/, classpath:/config,
  file:./, file:./config]). This does not expose the
  application.properties from the server to all clients, because any
  property sources present in the server are removed before being sent
  to the client.*
- **[Tip] A filesystem backend is great for getting started quickly and for testing. To use it in production, you need to be sure that the
  file system is reliable and shared across all instances of the Config
  Server.**